# problemas com 'multiple definition of...' em arquivos .O

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados

Olá, estou fazendo um programa para estudar listas e estou tendo um problema com as definições das funções, tentei resolver com meu professor de estruturas de dados mas não consegui intender direito, se alguém puder me ajudar, meu código é esse:

## main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include "menu.h"

//Programa principal
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Portuguese");

    aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&cabAeroporto);

    int op;

    menu(&op);

    return 0;
}
```

## menu.h:

```
#include "menu.c"

void Display_Menu();
void menu (int *op);
```

## menu.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "src\src.h"

//2 Constantes para controle do fluxo do programa, um para congelar a tela e outro para limpar
#define CLEAR "cls"
#define PAUSE "pause"


//Display do menu do sistema de controle aereo
void Display_Menu()
{
    system("cls");
    printf("            Menu            \n");
    printf("1- Cadastrar Aeroporto.\n");
    printf("2- Lista Aeroportos.\n");
    printf("3- Remove Aeroporto.\n");
    printf("4- Cadastrar Voo.\n");
    printf("5- Ver Voos do aeroporto.\n");
    printf("6- Ver Voos da companhia.\n");
    printf("7- Remove voo.\n");
    printf("8- Experimentar a viagem iterativa.\n");
    printf("0- Sair\n\n");
    printf("Escolha uma opcao:");

}

void menu (int *op)
{

    do{
        system(CLEAR);

        Display_Menu();

        scanf("%d",&*op);

        switch (*op){
            case 1:{
                cadastra_aeroporto(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                lista_aeroportos(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                remove_aeroportos(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 4:{
                cadastra_voo(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 5:{
                lista_voos_aeroporto(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 6:{
                lista_voos_companhia(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 7:{
                remove_voo(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
            case 8:{
                viagem_iterativa(cabAeroporto);
                break;
            }
        }

        system(PAUSE);

    }while(op != 0);
}
```

## src.h:

```
#include "src.c"

_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto;
```

## src.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

//Constantes para controle do fluxo do programa, um para congelar a tela e outro para limpar
#define CLEAR "cls"
#define PAUSE "pause"

//Estrutura tipo voo
typedef struct _voo{
    char companhia [50];
    int numero;
    struct _aeroporto* destino;
    struct _voo* proximo;
    struct _voo* anterior;

} _Voo;

//Estrutura tipo aeroporto
typedef struct _aeroporto{
    char nome [50];
    struct _voo* voos;
    struct _aeroporto* proximo;
    struct _aeroporto* anterior;

} _Aeroporto;
/*essa parte de declaração de funções, meu professor pediu para por aqui
ao invez de por no header*/
void aloca_memoria_aeroporto(_Aeroporto** aeroporto);
void aloca_memoria_voo();
void ler_dados_aeroporto();
void cadastra_aeroporto();
void lista_aeroportos();
void imprime_aeroporto();
void remove_aeroportos();
void cadastra_voo();
void ler_dados_voo();
void lista_voos_aeroporto();
void imprime_voo();
void lista_voos_companhia();
void remove_voo();
void viagem_iterativa();


//Busca na lista de aeroportos algum aeroporto cujo nome seja igual ao recebido
_Aeroporto* busca_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto, char nome_aeroporto[]){

    _Aeroporto* cursor;

    for(cursor = cabAeroporto->proximo ; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->proximo){
        if(strcmp(nome_aeroporto, cursor->nome) == 0){
            return cursor;
        }
  }
    return NULL;
}

//Recebe o nome do aeroporto de origem e de destino e verifica se existe algum voo parecido.
_Voo* busca_voo(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto, char origem[], char destino[]){

    _Voo* voos;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, origem);

    if(aeroporto){
        voos = aeroporto->voos;

        for(voo_cursor = voos->proximo ; voo_cursor != NULL; voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo){
            if(strcmp(destino, (voo_cursor->destino)->nome) == 0){
                return voo_cursor;
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

//Aloca memoria para um tipo _Aeroporto
void aloca_memoria_aeroporto(_Aeroporto** aeroporto){
    (*aeroporto) = (_Aeroporto*) malloc (sizeof(_Aeroporto));

    if ((*aeroporto) == NULL){
        printf("Falha na alocacao da memoria\n");
    }

    (*aeroporto)->proximo = NULL;
}

//Aloca memoria para um tipo _Voo
void aloca_memoria_voo(_Voo** voo){
    (*voo) = (_Voo*) malloc (sizeof(_Voo));

    if ((*voo) == NULL){
        printf("Falha na alocacao da memoria\n");
    }

    (*voo)->proximo = NULL;
}

//Cadastra aeroporto
void cadastra_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){
    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Aeroporto* cursor;

    // Obtem o endereco do cabeca
    cursor = cabAeroporto;

    // Aloca a memoria para um novo elemento
    aloca_memoria_aeroporto(&aeroporto);
    aloca_memoria_voo(&aeroporto->voos);

    // Le o dados a serem cadastrados
    ler_dados_aeroporto(aeroporto);

    if(busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, aeroporto->nome)){
        printf("Nome de aeroporto já registrado!\n");
    }

    // Navega ate o fim da lista
    while (cursor->proximo != NULL){
        cursor = cursor->proximo;
    }

    // Insere o novo elemento no fim da lista
    cursor->proximo = aeroporto;
    aeroporto->anterior = cursor;
}

//Faz a leitura de dados do aeroporto
void ler_dados_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* aeroporto){
    printf("Nome do aeroporto: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", aeroporto->nome);
}

// Varre a lista de aeroportos e imprime-os
void lista_aeroportos(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* cursor;

    printf("Aeroportos da lista\n\n");

    for(cursor = cabAeroporto->proximo ; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->proximo){
        imprime_aeroporto(cursor);
    }
}

//Imprime os dados de um aeroporto
void imprime_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){
    printf("Nome do aeroporto: %s\n",cabAeroporto->nome);
}

//Remove um aeroporto da lista de aeroportos
void remove_aeroportos(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    char nome_aux[50];

    printf("Nome do aeroporto para ser removido: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_aux);

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_aux);

    if(aeroporto){
        (aeroporto->anterior)->proximo = aeroporto->proximo;
         printf("Aeroporto remotivo com sucesso!\n\n");
    }else{
        printf("Nenhum aeroporto com este nome foi encontrado!\n\n");
    }
}

//Cadastra voo
void cadastra_voo(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Voo* voo;
    _Voo* cursor_voo;
    _Aeroporto* origem;
    _Aeroporto* destino;
    char nome_origem[50];
    char nome_destino[50];

    // Aloca a memoria para um novo elemento
    aloca_memoria_voo(&voo);

    // Le o dados a serem cadastrados
    ler_dados_voo(voo);

    printf("Nome da origem: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_origem);

    origem = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_origem);

    if(origem){
        cursor_voo = origem->voos;
    }else{
        printf("Nenhum aeroporto com este nome foi encontrado!\n\n");
    }

    printf("Nome do destino: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_destino);

    if(busca_voo(cabAeroporto, nome_origem ,nome_destino)){
        printf("Voo jï¿½ programado!\n");
    }

    destino = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_destino);

    if(destino){
        voo->destino = destino;
    }else{
        printf("Nenhum aeroporto com este nome foi encontrado!\n\n");
    }

    while (cursor_voo->proximo != NULL){
        cursor_voo = cursor_voo->proximo;
    }

    // Insere o novo elemento no fim da lista
    cursor_voo->proximo = voo;
    voo->anterior = cursor_voo;

    printf("Voo adicionado com sucesso!\n\n");
}

//Coleta os dadados do voo vindos do usuï¿½rio
void ler_dados_voo(_Voo* voo){
    printf("Nï¿½mero do voo: ");
    scanf("%d", &voo->numero);

    printf("Nome da companhia aï¿½rea: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", voo->companhia);
}

//Lista todos os voos que saem de um determinado aeroporto
void lista_voos_aeroporto(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voos;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    char nome_aux[50];

    printf("Nome do aeroporto: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_aux);

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_aux);

    if(aeroporto){

        voos = aeroporto->voos;

        for(voo_cursor = voos->proximo ; voo_cursor != NULL; voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo){
            imprime_voo(voo_cursor);
        }

    }else{
        printf("Aeroporto nï¿½o encontrado!\n");
    }
}

//Imprime na tela os dados de um voo
void imprime_voo(_Voo* voo){
    printf("Nï¿½mero do voo: %d\n",voo->numero);
    printf("Nome da companhia: %s\n",voo->companhia);
    printf("Aeroporto de destino: %s\n",(voo->destino)->nome);
}

//Lista todos os voos que saem de um determinado companhia aerea
void lista_voos_companhia(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    char nome_aux[50];

    aeroporto = cabAeroporto;

    printf("Nome da companhia: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_aux);

    while (aeroporto->proximo != NULL){

        aeroporto = aeroporto->proximo;
        voo_cursor = aeroporto->voos;

        while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
            voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;

            if(strcmp(nome_aux, voo_cursor->companhia) == 0){
                printf("De %s para %s:\n",aeroporto->nome, (voo_cursor->destino)->nome);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Remove voo de uma lista de voos
void remove_voo(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voo_cursor;
    char nome_origem[50];
    char nome_destino[50];

    aeroporto = cabAeroporto;

    printf("Nome do aeroporto de origem: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_origem);

    aeroporto = busca_aeroporto(cabAeroporto, nome_origem);

    if(aeroporto){

        printf("Nome do aeroporto de destino: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", nome_destino);

        voo_cursor = aeroporto->voos;

        while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
            voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;

            if(strcmp(nome_destino, (voo_cursor->destino)->nome) == 0){
                (voo_cursor->anterior)->proximo = voo_cursor->proximo;
                printf("Aeroporto remotivo com sucesso!\n\n");
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("Aeroporto nï¿½o encontrado!\n");
    }
}

//Faz uma viagem iterativa com o usuï¿½rio
void viagem_iterativa(_Aeroporto* cabAeroporto){

    _Aeroporto* aeroporto;
    _Voo* voo_inicial = NULL;
    _Voo* voo_cursor = NULL;
    int op, aux;

    aeroporto = cabAeroporto;

    if(aeroporto->proximo == NULL){
        printf("Nï¿½o existe aeroportos cadastrados!\n");
    }

    while (aeroporto->proximo != NULL){

        aeroporto = aeroporto->proximo;

        if((aeroporto->voos)->proximo != NULL){
            voo_inicial = aeroporto->voos;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(voo_inicial == NULL){
        printf("Nenhum voo cadastrado!\n");
    }

    do{
        voo_cursor = voo_inicial;
        aux = 0;
        system(CLEAR);

        printf("            Voos do aeroporto %s!            \n", aeroporto->nome);

        while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
            voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;
            imprime_voo(voo_cursor);
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n0- Sair\n\n");
        printf("Escolha um voo:");

        scanf("%d",&op);

        voo_cursor = voo_inicial;

        if(op != 0){
            while (voo_cursor->proximo != NULL){
                voo_cursor = voo_cursor->proximo;
                if(voo_cursor->numero == op){
                    voo_inicial = (voo_cursor->destino)->voos;
                    aeroporto = voo_cursor->destino;
                    aux++;
                }
            }

            if(aux == 0){
                printf("Número de voo incorreto!\n");
                system(PAUSE);
            }
        }

    }while(op != 0);

}
```

os erros que estão dando estão nesta foto:

[imagem_do_erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re51L.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não faças includes de ficheiros com extensão .c!

Mete a definição de estruturas em ficheiros .h (a `struct _voo` e a `struct _aeroporto`).

Mete os protótipos de funções em ficheiros .h.

Mete os *[include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)* nos teus ficheiros .h.

Comment: eu ainda to com o mesmo erro né y.y'' meu deus eu vou resolver isso hoje @pmg prometo

Comment: mas como que eu vou encontrar o que tem no src.c por exemplo, se o src.h nao chama o src.c

Comment: Parte da compilação chama-se a *linkagem* (ou *mistura*). Esta parte pega no resultado da compilação de diferentes ficheiros .c e mistura-os para obter um resultado onde está tudo disponível. Os compiladores recentes escondem bastante deste processo fazendo tudo automaticamente. Que sistema usas para escrever código, compilar, e debugar?

Comment: `Windows 8.1` `gnu+gcc` `IDE Falcon c/c++` os mesmos que o informei numa outra pergunta recente, na verdade eu ainda não intendi muito bem como fazer, a parte teórica eu intendi bem.Só não sei o que fazer (intendo como o erro acontece)

Comment: [assim você quis dizer?](https://i.imgur.com/vCWGhVm.jpg)

Comment: Eu nao conheco o Falcon, mas olhando para a imagem, acho que vais precisar de mudar os ficheiros menu.h, main.c, e menu.c para a pasta src. Depois F9 ...

Comment: não pois quando eu chamo o src.h e .c eu chamo eles diretamente na pasta

Comment: Amanha eu experimento esse Falcon com o teu codigo no trabalho. Aqui em casa so tenho Unix; nao da para instalar.

Comment: ja tentou usar o sublime text? acho que nao difere muito

Comment: Verifica no [meu github](https://github.com/hexkid/se-pt/tree/master/pt68014). Eu vou mudando os ficheiros aos poucos, está com atenção às mudanças :)

Comment: Já compila e corre (com erros) no meu Falcon ... http://snag.gy/l11nO.jpg

Comment: na verdade(reescrevendo o comentário), no meu compila com um monte de erro em `.O como main.o, menu.o e src.o` mas não corre

Comment: meu professor falou comigo para eu nao usar `include guard` por enquanto por não ter falado sobre isso em aula ainda, mas me garantiu que é um modo de resolver sim, vou até dar uma olhada a mais nesse assunto para intender mais. sobre a solução do problema vou fazer somente com um header só pois esta dando muito problema fazer sem o include guard. obrigado pmg =)